# LDAP binding in Perl when OU is unknown

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

Is there a way to successfully bind while leaving out one of the files in the bind search base string? I don't always know what $site is for a user and if I leave it out the binding fails. Can I have something like OU=*,

```
 $ldapSearchBase = "OU=$site,OU=xxxx,OU=xxxx,DC=$globalLocation,DC=companyName,DC=com";
```

If I leave the site out I get. it works if I put in my correct site

```
The wrong password was supplied or the SASL credentials could not be processed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP binds require you to have a single unique distinguished name plus the appropriate credentials (user/pass, SSL, etc.).  Your bind will always fail if your DN is not unique.

You might want to try splitting your base DN and varying whatever `$site` is:

```
my $ldapSearchBase = "OU=user,OU=accounts,DC=$globalLocation,DC=companyName,DC=com";
my $ldapSite = "OU=$site";
my $bindString = $ldapSearch . "," . $ldapSearchBase;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the first container as search base:

```
$ldapSearchBase = "DC=$globalLocation,DC=companyName,DC=com";
```